# Section footer of UITableView is moving when keyboard is appearing

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView with different sections in it. Each section has its own footer (just a grey line for design reasons). When clicking on a table view cell in a section an AlertView and the keyboard appears (to enter a password). But when the keyboard appears the footer of the section is pushed up by the keyboard. U can see it behind the AlertView in the grey background. Looks very ugly.

How can i avoid that? The footer in the background should stay where it was (on the bottom of the section). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a work around for this which worked for me, set `tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0`  when `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0
    tableView.endUpdates()
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 100
    tableView.endUpdates()
    return true
}
```

Make sure you're setting the footerView height using `tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 100` in `viewDidLoad()` and not using the  `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat`